# How do I check how many wisps are left in an area?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

I would like to check which areas I still have uncollected wisps in. I know the game tells me how many wisps are left after I collect a wisp, but I can't remember which areas I've cleared.

How do I check how many wisps are left in an area?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to Jubilife Village and talk to Vessa, the child who gave you the Wisp collecting quest. Select "How many wisps are left?" and she will say how many wisps are left in each area.

[image: asking how many wisps are left]

[image: being told how many wisps are left]